# Read/upload to google drive directly without creating temp files with the googledrive package from tidyverse

Tags: r, google-drive-api, tidyverse

I was wondering if it is possible to read/upload files to google drive without creating local temp files. That is, without first downloading a file from drive, reading it into R and modifying it, then saving it locally and uploading it to drive. But rather read a google sheet, say, directly into R and then upload the dataframe directly to google drive as a google sheet.

After reading the reference manual and some references on tidyverse.org, it seems like it is possible to read from drive but not upload a dataframe directly from R, but I might have missed something.

Comment: Hi @Preben, try this one - [link](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org)

Comment: check the google sheets api